# VMware Host only network - Cannot connect to mysql between VMs

Tags: mysql, vmware-workstation

I've setup a virtual private network using VMware workstation 11.
IPs are configured as so:

- Host: 192.168.129.1    Physical machine
- VM: 192.168.129.3      MariaDb database
- VM: 192.168.129.4      Web app

I'm using CentOS 7 for VMs and i'm trying to connect from the .4 web app to the .3 database.

Ping test are ok for all machines in every direction.

Mysql settings:

```
 Bind address is 192.168.129.3

 Privileges are granted for root and web app user for the correct database.
```

VM settings:

```
 Selinux is disabled, port 3306 is opened with IPtables...
```

I've spent the morning trying a thousand things but, nope, still no connection.

Here's the error I get when i try to connect with mysql directly:

```
   mysql -p -h 192.168.129.3
```

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.129.3' (113)

What did I miss ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: errno 113 is "No route to host".  That's either firewall or routing config fail.

Comment: When i try

$> route -n

Comment: 0.0.0.0           192.168.129.1     0.0.0.0     UG    100     0    0  eno167777

Comment: 192.168.129.0   0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U     100     0    0  eno167777

Comment: Doesn't it seems correct ? Thanks womble

Comment: You write ".4 database", but you bind to .3? If the MariaDB host has the IP-address 192.168.129.4, you should bind it to the correct address.

Comment: My bad !

 .4 is the web app and .3 is the database.  (Edited post)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Womble for giving me the clue.

My firewall was still blocking traffic. In fact, I'd disabled Selinux while firewalld was active.

So that did the trick:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I had the same issue and firewall was the problem. There is no need to stop/disable firewall, just allow MySQL port to the firewall: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent` than `firewall-cmd --reload`.